# How to loop though XElements and compare values using C#

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

I have an XElement which contains similar nodes but different values.
Like my `XElement` look like this

```
<Information>
    <Emp>
        <A.EMPLID>1</A.EMPLID>
        <A.Phone>12##</A.Phone>
    </Emp>
    <Emp_Add>
        <B.ID>125</B.ID>
        <Add>XXXXXXX</Add>
    </Emp_Add>
    <Emp_Add>
        <B.ID>1256</B.ID>
        <Add>ZZZZZZ</Add>
    </Emp_Add>
</Information>
```

Actually I need to go through each `<Emp_Add>` node - pick up the value of `<B.ID>`
and compare it with `<Emp>.<A.EMPLID>` value. If values are same then display message `"Values matched"` else message `"Values does not match"` using C# code.

How to use for each loop and compare for such `XElement`.

Comment: Can you vote and/or comment if my answer was util for you?

Comment: It's time to read this excellent book [Pro LINQ in C# 2010](https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430226536) to be more familiar with LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

See my [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7qUBo2).

```
var xml =
                "<Information>\r\n\t<Emp>\r\n\t\t<A.EMPLID>1</A.EMPLID>\r\n\t\t<A.Phone>12##</A.Phone>\r\n\t</Emp>\r\n\t<Emp_Add>\r\n\t\t<B.ID>125</B.ID>\r\n\t\t<Add>XXXXXXX</Add>\r\n\t</Emp_Add>\r\n\t<Emp_Add>\r\n\t\t<B.ID>1256</B.ID>\r\n\t\t<Add>ZZZZZZ</Add>\r\n\t</Emp_Add>\r\n</Information>";
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
        XDocument xmlObj = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.OuterXml);

        var emplId = xmlObj.Descendants().Descendants().Descendants().FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var empsAdd = xmlObj.Descendants().Descendants().Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "Emp_Add");
        foreach (var emp in empsAdd)
        {
            var currentEmpIdNode = emp.Descendants().FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(currentEmpIdNode != null && currentEmpIdNode.Value == emplId
                              ? "Values matched"
                              : "Values does not match");
        }
```